# Offline Storage Using IndexedDB

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-web-api, indexeddb, offline-storage

**Requirement:** To create a web application in ASP.NET targeting mobile devices, especially ipads which will have the "Offline Storage Functionality" when the app is not connected to internet.

**My Plan:**

1. To use "IndexedDB" in order to store data when not connected to internet.
2. To use ASP.NET to pull data stored offline and sync it with MSSQL Server.

**I Achieved:**

1. CRUD using IndexedDB.

**I'm Unaware Of:**

1. How to use ASP.NET to pull data stored offline and sync it with MSSQL Server when app is connected to internet.

How do I achieve my requirement? Your time and help are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Well, without thinking too much, the data that are stored in the device while offline need to have some identification, for you to know what was synced and what wasn't. Are you planning to always try to send changes to the server, and if it can't, save if locally? You also need to define when you want to "check" if changes were made locally and when you want to send them back to the server.